# Maxima CAS, Solve(), heap exhausted

Tags: maxima-software

I have 13 equations, using variables named d1 .. d13. I give you 3 examples of them:

eq 1 :$$-1512306498003420269625002340551784=\mathrm{d13}^2-73976030 \mathrm{d12}
$$
eq 2 :$$\text{{some 220 digit integer}} =\mathrm{d1}^2- \text{{some 120 digit integer }}\mathrm{d2}^2
$$
eq 3:
$$53224924879680228591105839482631095894942304639505087943900593662151240330638513930240=-2 \mathrm{d11}\, \mathrm{d9}+2 \mathrm{d12}\, \mathrm{d8}-2 \mathrm{d13}\, \mathrm{d7}+73976030 \mathrm{d6}+\mathrm{d10}^2
$$

And so on. To be clear: {some xxx digit integer} ofcourse means an actual number, not a variable. The same kind of equations, but in a smaller ammount, were solvable.

I then call solve():

sol : solve([eq13, eq12, eq11, eq10, eq9, eq8, eq7, eq6, eq5, eq4, eq3, eq2, eq1]);

It takes about ten minutes to calculate, and then crashes because the heap is exhausted. Are there things I can improve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand the context here.  You are surprised that if you make the numbers big and ugly enough that a computer struggles to handle them?  How is that a surprise?  Why would you think that you can circumvent that and improve things beyond what the software is already doing?

Comment: recommend you give it just one equation,   your eq 2   which is of Pell type  $x^2 - a y^2 = b$  with large $a,b$   Your computer might give you an answer.   Then read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27s_cattle_problem

Comment: meanwhile, suggest you also solve the variant of your equation 2 given by $x^2 - a y^2 = 1.$   You   call my $a$ " some 120 digit integer.  "  Assuming   your $a > 0$  there are infinitely many solutions to eq 2, ...   Meanwhile, do you mean your variables to be integers?????

Comment: As a reaction to the comments: Thank you. I tried converting my big integers into floats, but had the same problem. Solving eq2 first expresses one variable as a function of the other (a square root plus a constant), I inserted this solution in the rest of my equations and again called solve(), but then it almost immediately came back with: "algsys: Couldn't reduce system to a polynomial in one variable.".

Comment: To give you some background and conclusion: I am developing electronic filters of a quite High order. Not to actually build them but to investigate a new approach. The conclusion seems to be that a this High order is simply to much for Maxima.

Comment: Maybe Mathematica or [Pari GP online](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) can handle it

Comment: @Erik-JanO  if you wish to reply to a comment and have that person be notified about your reply, you need   to type in an @   sign followed by the first few letters of that username; at that point you should be given the full username to click on. Meanwhile,  complete solutions for Pell $x^2 - a y^2 = 1$  and variants $x^2 - a y^2 = b$   are available; I don't know any online resource that spits it out  and handles all possible details.